# Functions working in remix but not in testnet

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, ropsten, crowdsale

The functions `remainingToken()` and `totalContribution()` are not working in testnet but working in remix.

```
function  remainingToken() public view ownable returns (uint remainingSupply)  {

        return (balances[address(this)]);
    }

    //Real time

    function presenTime () public view returns ( uint){
        return block.timestamp;
    }  
   
    //Total Supply
    
    function totalSupply() public override view returns (uint) {
        return maximumSupply ;
    }
     
    //Total Ether Contributed  
    
    function totalContribution() public ownable view returns(uint){
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    //Token balance of any address 

    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public override view returns (uint balance) {
        return balances[tokenOwner];
    }

    //Check Allowance

    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public override view returns (uint remaining) {
        return allowed[tokenOwner][spender];
    }
```

[image: TESTNET INTERACTION]

[image: REMIX INTERACTION]

Comment: Just wanna know, after deploying the contract to the testnet, have you called the functions from other addresses and contributed eth from those accounts before calling the above functions you have mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you share the contract link?

Also can you explain why you applied a "ownable" modifier to view functions?

Comment: 0x5942a9e591Ef9d84a708C080304dc36B17e33b01 I redeployed the contract

Comment: Will removing Ownable work???

Comment: Removing ownable worked.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you haven't used other address to make contributions by sending eth or call other functions after deploying to the testnet.

You should know that whatever the transactions you have made in the remix they belong to the remix only.

And you have to make new transactions in the tesnet to get the expected results.

Comment: Hii thanks for replying.
I used 3 other addresses to send ether to the contract. Everything is working fine.
Only these two functions are not returning the expected values they are just returning zero.